# Is there stringy Morse theory?

Tags: string-theory

This question is pretty vague and open. I'm just curious if anyone has considered this.

Morse theory has a nice physical formulation: a Morse function can be thought of as a potential, so the gradient flow is the force experienced by a particle. The equilibria are the critical points of the potential. If we take a supersymmetric extension of this as a quantum theory, its ground state structure computes the homology of the space the particle moves in.

What can strings moving in a manifold subject to a potential tell us about the topology of the manifold?

Answer (score 9):

You have to consider [Picard-Lefschetz theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lefschetz_theory) instead [Morse theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) and find what a stringy analog to $N=2$ SUSY QM is. An analog might be constructed from a new look at the [path integral formulation](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789812386502_bmatter) of (complexified) $N=2$ SUSY QM (see [Edward Witten's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6032) and [Stephan Zheng's master thesis](http://web.science.uu.nl/ITF/teaching/2011/Stephan%20Zheng.pdf)). You might also consider [string topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_topology).

Comment: See [Huijun Fan's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1290v1.pdf) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! These look like some good references.

Answer (score 4):

Properties of Riemannian, Kähler and hyperKähler manifolds could be seen through dimensional reductions of source spaces (domains) of corresponding quantum SUSY non-linear [sigma-models](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sigma-model), models whose target spaces (codomains) are the above mentioned manifolds, e.g. you get $N=2$ SUSY QM i.e. quantum superparticle moving in a Riemannian manifold as a [dimensional reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_reduction) of 2d $N=1+1$ quantum [non-linear sigma-model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_sigma_model) over superMinkowski spacetime (1+1)|(1,1), a quantum non-linear sigma-model which is again a dimensional reduction of 3d $N=2$ quantum non-linear sigma model over superMinkowski spacetime (1+2)|2. $\mathbb{Z}$-grading of forms on a Riemannian manifold is the relic of $R$-symmetry i.e $SO(2)$-group of superPoincare group $P^{3|2}$.

Deformations of the above mentioned SUSY non-linear models are done via superpotentials which are expressed by corresponding real or holomorphic Morse functions.

Read [Dan Freed's book](http://books.google.rs/books/about/Five_Lectures_on_Supersymmetry.html?id=JHkCFapC3i0C&redir_esc=y) about the above mentioned.

Regarding your question, see also:

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0311064

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401175

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407122

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0509163

and

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702137

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610149

http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3302

http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/archives/001030.html

http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/07/notes_from_stringmath_2012.html

Comment: I've merged your accounts again, which means that you can edit your two answer together. I really would like to encourage you to register: unregistered accounts are browser based and will lose contact from time to time.

Comment: For others' references : http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6545  I agree that the edit was justly rejected, but         it may be that the suggester was the OP himself . The link added was: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10773-010-0586-9